# How to close command prompt Window in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to close the command prompt window which I have opened in my ruby script using
    `system("start cmd.exe")`

I cannot use "exit" command as there is some batch file running in the command prompt, I need to terminate that Window and close the command prompt.

Please help me to close Window.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
cmdprompt = Process.spawn 'start cmd.exe' # open prompt
Process.kill 9, cmdprompt                 # close it
```

Not sure will it work for Windows, though.

There is gem `win32-process` that provides ability to handle external processes on Windows, try this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'win32/process'
cmdprompt = Process.create(:app_name => 'cmd')   # open
Process.kill 9, cmdprompt.process_id             # close
```

I have no ability to test it, but think it shoul work.

Comment: No its not working in windows, could you please suggest me some other way

Comment: its still not working, script is giving following error at       `Process.kill 9, cmdprompt`                C:\Documents and Settings\xsat314\Desktop>(eval):3:in `call': can't convert Struct::ProcessInfo into Integer (TypeError)
 from (eval):3:in `OpenProcess'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-process-0.5.3/lib/win32/process.rb:143:in `kill'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-process-0.5.3/lib/win32/process.rb:132:in `each'
 from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-process-0.5.3/lib/win32/process.rb:132:in `kill'

Comment: @wani: try replacing `Process.kill 9, cmdprompt` with `Process.kill 9, cmdprompt.process_id`.

Comment: Hey also the above code will not open a new command prompt window, it will open an existing one, how do i modify this code to include it to open new command prompt window by itself.