# How to close the command prompt when running a batch file in ruby in windows

Tags: ruby

am opening command prompt using system command like system("start cmd.exe") and then running some batch file. I want to stop the batch file running in command prompt or close the command prompt window. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close command prompt Window in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910680/how-to-close-command-prompt-window-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the command prompt to terminate you just write the following in your script..:

```
system("exit")
```

To stop the batch file I will use win32ole lib and send a CTRL+C combo like this..:

```
require "win32ole"

key = WIN32OLE.new('Wscript.Shell')

key.SendKeys('{^}C{ENTER}')
```

Comment: This didn't work in my Login Script for arachni security scanner

Comment: Maybe give some more info. Like share the script perhaps, or how you start the script? Is it .bat file?